# Can I cash or deposit a American Express Travelers Cheque if it does not have my signature at the top?

Tags: check, cash, deposits, travel, american-express

I am in Orange County California, and I went on a trip with my Aunts & Cousins, all of us exchanged our money at once. We can our money to my Aunt, and she gave us checks with her signature on the top back. Was no problem to use them in Brazil, but now we are back in America, and I would like to get my $100 back. I live in California and she lives in Minnesota though. So is there anyway for me to get the money off it without having her present to sign it & get it cashed for me?

Thank you!

Comment: Mail it to her, have her mail you a normal check in return....

Comment: Traveler checks are signed upon receipt by the person who had initially bought them. The way they work is that they are particularly hard to *steal*, because the cashing procedure involves being watched as you countersign. The signatures must match.

Answer (score 2):

Traveller check require one signature at top when the check are purchased. Matching signature at bottom when you want to encash.

So if there is no signature, you would need to get her signature, or as suggested mail it to her and get a regular check.